# How to set session time out

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have an old project which is using Spring (3.2.1.RELEASE) and hibernate-core (3.6.10.Final). Basically, I need to set the time out when any query takes more than 30 seconds to execute.

Please find below my existing spring configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd">

    <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
             <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="${jndi.x.name}"></jee:jndi-lookup>
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourceConfig" jndi-name="${jndi.y.name}"></jee:jndi-lookup>



    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- configure hibernate session factory for Local database -->

    <bean id="sessionFactoryConfig"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceConfig"/>
        <property name="configLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <!--    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> -->
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">false</prop>
      
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is find below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="sessionFactoryConfig">
        <!-- Please keep this in alphabetical order (ascending) -->
        <mapping resource="mappings/named_queries.xml" />
        <mapping class="dummy.test" />
        <mapping class="dummy.test2" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have seen the following config:

```
hibernate.c3p0.timeout
```

But based on what I have read, it will remove unused connection in a pool not time out an active session if it is taking more than 30 seconds.

Any idea how I can achieve the global time out functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The Hibernate configuration is for setting query timeout is:

```
javax.persistence.query.timeout
```

If using Springboot application properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=123
```